# JMeter BeanShell Assertion comparison

Tags: apache, jmeter, beanshell

I don't understand my BeanShell Assertion response in Apache JMeter.

```
int varcount = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("getcount"));
if ((varcount) < 25000) {
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "testnsg";
}
```

`getcount` value is 39000. I need to be alerted and the test to be stopped when it is below 25000. However, above script is running fine without any errors, and when I change the comparison to `((varcount) > 25000)` then i get an alert and the result is"

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: testnsg
```

It's the opposite of what I would expect. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is absotuely expected. 39000 is more than 25000 hence your assertion never fails.

[image: Beanshell comparison operators]

See:

- [Equality and Relational Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) to learn that do `>` and `<` mean
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) - for extended information on using Java and JMeter APIs in scripting test elements